# How do I use the 64-Bit Tonic without lowering the framerate?

Tags: yooka-laylee

Yooka-Laylee added a [64-Big Tonic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gk025zr3C_g) which downgrades the graphics and cuts the framerate from 60fps to 20fps. I enjoy the downgraded graphics but the lowered framerate gives me a headache.

Is there a way to play with the 64-Bit Tonic graphics without lowering the game's framerate?

Comment: Haven't tested myself, but there's a [mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/yookalaylee/mods/3) to uncap the framerate (and removes CRT effect; can be changed with their config). I don't know if it works on current version, hence comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.
Since it's emulating an old system, the low framerate is locked and intended. Which is unfortunate, because the old-style graphics looks so good by itself.